# ERROR : "name or service not known" in kubernetes while calling grpc from api in same cluster using https domains(working using ip address on http)

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-ingress

we have kubernetes deployed api and grpc in same cluster and grpc set under sub domain and grpc on https are working when access on local but when try to connect from api hosted in same cluster gives error as "name or service not known"

Comment: It's not possible to answer questions with so little details. Kubernetes programs internal DNS for services etc. I suspect you're not referencing the services correctly within the cluster. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ It would help if you include examples of the commands you're running and the output you're receiving. Please reread your question and consider how someone who only understands your issue through your question would be able to answer it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it is not coding issue, it is deployment issue in kubernetes for example i have two microservices api hosted in cluster when i try to connect one api from other i got above issue but i am not able to find out the root cause of it.